# Internal C++ object already deleted error in Pyside2

Tags: python, pyside2

I am trying to create a list(like `QComboBox`) inside `QTreeWidget` in `Pyside2`. Whenever I click inside the cell to invoke this list, it throws me error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "customQT.py", line 1489, in event
    self.popup.move(Globpos)
RuntimeError: Internal C++ object (PySide2.QtWidgets.QListView) already deleted.
```

"trial_justifier_gui" is the name for the .py file for the GUI

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QWidget
from trial_justifier_gui import Ui_MainWindow
import os
import sys
from sys import argv
from os import path,listdir,remove,startfile,mkdir
from customQT import  MyLineXML,MyComboXML,MyMeasureXML
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from Mylogger import *
from shutil import copy2
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.etree.ElementTree import SubElement, Element
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *




class justifier(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self,PathProject):
        #super(justifier, self).__init__()
        listbaseline = ['']
        
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent=None)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.btnCreateBaselineNew.clicked.connect(self.analysispath)


    def analysispath(self):

        self.ReqTree = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget(self.ui.tab_2)
        self.ReqTree.clear()    
        self.ReqTree.setColumnCount(6)
        self.ReqTree.setHeaderLabels(["File", "Line", "Item", "Message","Justification ","Status"])
        
        self.ReqTree.header().setDefaultAlignment(Qt.AlignVCenter)
  
        self.ReqTree.setWordWrap(True)

        Line2 = MyComboXML(statusElem,["NEW","OK","KO","DELETED"],True)
        Line2.modified.connect(self.modif)

        self.ReqTree.setItemWidget(childBisPN,1,Line2)
```

The class MyComboXML which is used to create the List and populate the status is:

The piece of code which invokes this class is:

```
class MyComboXML(QLineEdit):

        modified = Signal()

        def __init__(self,elem,text,editable):
            QLineEdit.__init__(self)
            self.liste = text
            self.filter = ""
            self.elem = elem
            self.editable = editable

            self.listPopup = None
            self.listTooltip = None
            self.setText(elem.text)
            self.setMouseTracking(True)
            self.createModel()

            # connect signals
            self.textEdited.connect(self.pFilterModel.setFilterFixedString)
            self.textChanged.connect(self.modifyText)

            # self.completer.activated.connect(self.on_completer_activated)    
            self.isVisible = False
            if not self.editable :
                self.readOnly()

        def createModel(self):

            self.model = QStandardItemModel()
            self.model.setRowCount(len(self.liste))
            self.model.setColumnCount(1)
            row = 0
            for item in self.liste:
                itemModel = QStandardItem()
                # itemModel.setToolTip(item)
                itemModel.setText(item)
                self.model.setItem(row, 0, itemModel)
                row = row + 1
            # self.popup.setModel(self.model)

            self.pFilterModel = QSortFilterProxyModel(self.model)
            self.pFilterModel.setFilterCaseSensitivity(Qt.CaseInsensitive)
            self.pFilterModel.setSourceModel(self.model)

            # add a completer, which uses the filter model
            self.completer = QCompleter(self.pFilterModel, self)
            # always show all (filtered) completions
            self.completer.setCompletionMode(QCompleter.UnfilteredPopupCompletion)
            self.popup =self.completer.popup()
            self.setCompleter(self.completer)
            
        def event(self,e):
            #print(e.type())
            if (e.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonPress):
                if self.editable:
                    #popup =self.completer.popup()
                    Globpos = self.parent().mapToGlobal(self.pos())
                    Globpos.setY(Globpos.y()+self.height()-2)
                    **self.popup.move(Globpos)**

                    if self.isVisible:
                        self.popup.hide()
                        self.isVisible = False
                    else:
                        self.popup.show()
                        self.isVisible = True

            return QLineEdit.event(self,e)
```

I am running the justifier class through:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app=0
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = justifier(current_directory)
    app.processEvents()
    try:
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
    except:
        print("Exiting")
```

The code for GUI file is as follows:

```
from PySide2.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QDate, QDateTime, QMetaObject,
    QObject, QPoint, QRect, QSize, QTime, QUrl, Qt)
from PySide2.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QCursor, QFont,
    QFontDatabase, QIcon, QKeySequence, QLinearGradient, QPalette, QPainter,
    QPixmap, QRadialGradient)
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        if not MainWindow.objectName():
            MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1200, 700)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QSize(1200, 700))
        MainWindow.setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet(u"background-color: rgb(230, 242, 255);")
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")

        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName(u"verticalLayoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QRect(110, 300, 1000, 400))
        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout")
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.tabWidget = QTabWidget(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName(u"tabWidget")
        self.tab = QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName(u"tab")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.tab_2 = QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName(u"tab_2")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")

        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.tabWidget)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
```

Whenever the code for the pop-up is evoked, I am getting the error, and the application is exiting. This is the minimal reproducible example I can provide as I have included only the necessary modules in the code

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: hi eyllanesc, I have modified the code. I have included only the required modules now which is creating the list

Comment: It seems that you have not read the link, I want a runnable code and what you provide is not.

Comment: Hi eyllanesc, I have modified the code , and tried to produce the exact code which should be runnable with Pyside2. Sorry for my mistake in not understanding, as I am very new to this forum and trying to use this forum to my best.